# Time of relativistic scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, atomic-physics, collision, scattering

Consider a scattering collision between a **relativistic** electron and a Hydrogen atom, which is assumed to be in the ground state. Assume that the electron velocity is comparable to the speed of light $v \thicksim c$. Let's denote by $D$ the diameter of a ball, within which the probability to find the hydrogenic-electron (in the ground state) is at least 0.99.

What is needed is some reasonable bound on the time duration of the interaction, during collision between the electron and the Hydrogen atom.
Intuitively the interaction time can be estimated as
$$\Delta t \approx \mu \frac{D}{v} \hspace{3cm} \ast$$
where $\mu$  is some reasonable coefficient in the range of $0.333 < \mu < 3$.

Apparently just invoking classical mechanics won't do, since the objects are described by quantum wavefunctions and their motion by special relativity.
Yet some justified argument must exist to estimate and justify that, $\it{without}$ invoking the whole formalism of relativistic quantum scattering, which is extremely heavy.

From the principles of wavefunctions-overlap integrals, the fundamental definition of velocity the estimate above seems true.
Looking for better justified argumentation and estimation for the estimate above.